# Does Frequently used Memoji History reset If not used

Tags: iphone, emoji, history

This is a very important topic for me. The love of my life saw frequently used Memoji on my phone that she questioned.   I don’t blame her, I would have asked also. my question is how long do “Frequently used Memoji” stay listed when not used. These Memoji where from before I met her. Will the frequently used memoji reset to a default When not used or stay at the last used for ever?  Where do I find documentation on  the Algorithm to show her they are not recent and just last used from long ago?  Thanks. [image]

Comment: Why are you not sending your love all sorts of emoji? Fill up your tray with the new

Comment: I do send her emoji.  I’ve Not used the Memoji in a very long time.   It’s the Memoji she questions and I’ve not used them in forever.   I need documentation showing that it does not reset and has been there for a while.   She thinks they reset after a month and I can’t find documentation of that either

Comment: They stay forever afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Memoji stickers can be deleted in any app, tap the three dots, then tap the core Memoji and delete it. I’ve never seen them time out or go away, just new ones pile on top of the old as you use them.

[image: memoji you might love or love to delete]

Tap the Memoji identity you with to duplicate or delete.

[image: screen shot of the tools to delete or duplicate a Memoji identity]

As for the overall keyboard, you can reset all of the word suggestions, etc in the settings app. But you circled the Memoji which just exist until you delete the identities in the keyboard overlay itself.

- Settings > General > Reset > Reset Keyboard Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

There's only one way you can force reset your emojis from your recently used ones is to reset your dictionary by going into Settings > General > Reset > Reset Keyboard Dictionary. Another natural way your previously used emojis gradually fade away is when you use other emojis and they slowly slide back to the older used emojis until they finally disappear from your previously used emojis. You can get more info about this [here](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/clear-your-frequently-used-recent-emojis-from-your-iphones-keyboard-0194226/).

Comment: So to clarify. The only way the Memoji history changes or Disappears os if you reset it or use others to over write it.   Otherwise it just stays with last used if you never use them again?  Is that correct?

Comment: That's right @David!